# Is there a way to limit what session variables get exported as HTTP headers in a mule flow that involves a mid-flow HTTP transport?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm storing some data as session variables in a mule flow that involves a mid-flow http call to an external service.  I need this data for a subsequent branch of the flow logic, hence the session variable.  However, I do not want this data to go out with the http call as http headers.  Is there a way to limit which session variables mule includes as http headers in a given call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to decide what session property to propagate you can write a custom session handler and inject it into your http connector something like this:

```
<http:connector name="httpConnector">
   <service-overrides sessionHandler="your_session_handler" />  
</http:connector>
```

An example of a custom session handler can be found [here](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/core/src/main/java/org/mule/session/NullSessionHandler.java?source=c)

That said I'd like to echo David Dossot's answer: session variables should seldom be used, especially knowing how Mule leaks them by default. If you want to propagate something, you should set it explicitly as an outbound property and mule will propagate it.

Answer (score 1):

Use flow variables: session variables should seldom be used, especially knowing how Mule leaks them by default.

Flow variables (aka invocation properties) should be unaffected by endpoint interactions, this by design. Any other behaviour would be a bug. If your variables do not need to extend further than a flow, use flow variables, not session variables.

Comment: My understanding of flow variables was that they are synonymous with invocation properties, and similarly get eliminated when a message crosses a transport barrier.  Does Mule actually hold onto the invocation properties (aka flow variables), does not send along with outbound calls, but retains them in the subsequent components of a given flow?

Comment: Reviewed my answer with more explanation.

Comment: @David Dossett I presume you mean 'use flow variables, not session variables

Answer (score 0):

session variables are not sent across http calls, only session ID is sent via cookie (usually)

if you need to pass some data via http call to external domain - include them in GET, for example, as cookie are not shared

Comment: Are you talking about session variables in the context of Mule ESB flows?

Comment: @GarySharpe no, just about usual session variables which are used in all web applications, hoping that nobody change their meaning to something different